# How to make Google ask for password when switching between accounts

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-chrome

When using Gmail, have the option of switching between accounts by clicking the user icon in the upper right corner of the screen. Currently, can switch between the accounts listed when clicking the icon without any barriers (not having to enter a password or anything).

Why is this? Is there a way to change this so that would have to enter the password for the account before just being able to switch from one to the other?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is log out of those listed accounts (assuming they are not your delegated accounts) which will trigger the password request.

If they are your own delegated accounts you need to go to **Settings** and from each of your delegated accounts, you need to un-delegate them.